# Perl - No such pseudo-hash field

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I am a total Perl novice and trying to understand some code. I get the error

```
No such pseudo-hash field "value"
```

at the line

```
$stringObj->{'value'};
```

This is particularly hard to diagnose or debug because it magically starts working depending on the system. In the system I'm using, the error doesn't happen. However, all versions are running some form of Perl 5.8.

I understand that psuedo-hashes are kind of deprecated and I have no interest in continuing to use them -- I just need this code to work.

Here are my questions:

(1) If a psuedo-hash is treating a hash like an array, how can I correctly identify arrays and treat them as arrays?

(2) Why in the world does this bug appear and disappear seemingly at random?

On my machine, $stringObj might look like this:

$VAR1 = bless( { '_verify_isOK' => 1, 'name' => 'My Text', 'type' => 'StringEntity'}, 'MyObject' );

Sometimes it has a 'value' in there too.

Comment: Can you provide any more context?  What is `$stringObj`?

Comment: @JimDavis In all of the cases I can reproduce, $stringObj can be treated as a hash. Apparently this is not the form it takes on some other systems.

Comment: what sets $stringObj?

Answer (score 0):

You use an pseudo hash in perl. If you try to get a value with a nonexisting key you get your error message.

Example:

```
$stringObj = [ { "Billy" => 1, "Tom" => 2}, 22, 33 ]

print $stringObj->{'Billy'} 

22

print $stringObj->{'Steve'} 

No such pseudo-hash field "Steve"
```

Don't use Pseudeohashes. They are deprecated since 5.8.

Detailed description on book: Pro  Perl > Pseudohashes

https://books.google.de/books?id=1bbjLxkBLaMC&pg=PA130&lpg=PA130&dq=%22No+such+pseudo-hash+field%22+perl&source=bl&ots=GhbPNrWKGx&sig=D-UWQLMyU35ZeM1lGkIZEwkC0XE&hl=de&sa=X&ei=FYrLVOWnAuvW7Qbpp4GgCg&ved=0CG0Q6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22No%20such%20pseudo-hash%20field%22%20perl&f=false